# Where are the mining streets?

Tags: glitch-2011

While I was doing the exploration achievements, I remember two of the streets that are locked had a ton of mining nodes, but I can't remember which two. Anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two you're looking for is [Ajaya Bliss](http://www.glitch.com/locations/LA9154LI9R22R7A/) in Ilmenskie Deeps and [Neva Neva](http://www.glitch.com/locations/LDOU5PQU0FD21PF/) in Callopee. Both have a large number of fast spawning Sparkly rocks for easy mining and requires a [Teal-White Triangle key](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Teal-White_Triangle_Key) which is highly sought after and sells for [very high price on Auction](http://www.glitch.com/auctions/item-teal-white-triangle-key/).

Comment: I wouldn't call 2k high.

Comment: @antony.trupe Like everything in the game economy, the price on auction only reflects the demand and supply of the item. Whether you think its high or not is entirely up to what value you place on the item. However, you can get a bunch of friends to follow you through the door and split the cost of the key, or check out the wiki link for the spawn points for the key.

Comment: or fork over the 'not high' price of 2k and wait for the frog to show up :P we're agreeing with different words, I think.

Comment: Right now I wouldn't call 744 high.